# Treeview with changing controls in same window

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am re-designing some GUI items and want to implement something like the following:

[image]

[image]

As you change options in the TreeView on the left, the controls on the right change according to the option selected.

My question is, what is the best way to implement this? I was thinking of setting the visible property to true / false for each control to it's respective TreeView option selection; however, designing this on the VS GUI editor would be pretty painful as there would be hundreds of controls all over the place and on top of each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User controls. Create the blocks you have outlined in red as user controls and add/remove as you select/change node in the treeview.

If you want a "buffer" effect to avoid flicker when removing an existing control, then use a tab control with two pages (without showing the tabs.) Start with showing TAB1 then when selecting a node in the treeview add the correct control to TAB2 and then make TAB2 the active page. And then remove any existing controls from TAB1. And then the other way around when the next node is selected. etc etc.

Comment: Yes that is the best way to go about  it. Thanks for the info!